# TypeScript complains about unassigned variable despite exhaustive if/if else statement

Tags: typescript

Consider this code snippet:

```
type MyType = "value1" | "value2"

function myFunction(myParam: MyType) {
  let myString: string
  if(myParam === "value1") {
    myString = "foo1"
  }
  else if(myParam === "value2") {
    myString = "foo2"
  }
  myOtherFunction(myString) 
}

function myOtherFunction(anotherParam: string) { ... }
```

Since the `if/if else` handles all values of `myParam`, there is no way `myString` can be unassigned. Still, TypeScript complains: `Variable 'myString' is used before being assigned.`

How can I get rid of that error without substantial code changes?

(Of course, I could remove the `if(myParam === "value2")` part, but that makes the code much less readable. A `switch` works as well I think. But I dislike those.)

Comment: These are just string comparisons, so the compiler doesnt know that you are handling all the conditions. Better just use `else` with a comment near it for readability. Like: `else { //myParam === "value2"`

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17358

Comment: See [this](https://tsplay.dev/NddGnN)

Comment: What about if both cases are failed (if and else) ? You have handle all conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to "fix" this is to throw in an additional else

```
type MyType = "value1" | "value2"

function myFunction(myParam: MyType) {
  let myString: string
  if(myParam === "value1") {
    myString = "foo1"
  }
  else if(myParam === "value2") {
    myString = "foo2"
  }
  else {
    // const unknownType = myParam; // You can use this line to check what type is myParam
    throw new Error('myParam is wrong!');
  }

  // ...
}
```

By throwing in the else you ensure typescript that the path that should not be taken really cannot be taken.

---

Also for this kind of thing, I tend to use `switch` for clarity, but it is viable only for primitives...

Comment: This IMHO is the best solution. It will catch run-time errors -- e.g. if you cheat like this: `myFunction("blah" as  MyType);`

Answer (score 1):

The `if .. else` is exhaustive *only* when the last `else` does *not* have `if`:

```
type MyType = "value1" | "value2"

function myFunction(myParam: MyType) {
  let myString: string
  if(myParam === "value1") {
    myString = "foo1"
  }
  else { // <-- no "if" here
    myString = "foo2"
  }

  // `myString` is definitely assigned a value here

  myOtherFunction(myString)
}

function myOtherFunction(anotherParam: string) { ... }
```

Comment: I pointed to that option my question. I think it's less readable, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You could switch to `switch` <sup>*(ugh.., sorry)*</sup> and make the second case `default`:

```
type MyType = "value1" | "value2"

function myFunction(myParam: MyType) {
  let myString: string

  switch (myParam) {
    case "value1":
      myString = "foo1"
      break
    case "value2":
    default:
      myString = "foo2"
      break
  }

  myOtherFunction(myString)
}

function myOtherFunction(anotherParam: string) { ... }
```